# How to setup spring zuul gateway to use cilent_credentials oauth2 flow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-oauth2

Hi I have a resource service that is behind zuul gateway which serves angular application. The resource service have some endpoints restricted with #oauth2.isClient. How do I setup zuul gateway so it will perform authorisation using oauth2 cilent_credentials flow for the restricted resources? Secret, access token and client id are stored in gateway application property file. Note I do not want authenticate the user only simply the client.

Comment: Spring Cloud Security is what you need: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/

Comment: Sorry but I have spring security implemented in both microservices. I have difficulties in finding example implementing this specific clinet_credential oauth2 flow. SSO where you are authenticating client and user using auth service works nicely out of the box.